# in jframe one jpanel is overwritten by another jpannel"

Tags: swing, jframe, jpanel

I created a application with netbeans in one jframe with in 4jpannels. When I'm pressing one jbutton the jpanel opened and close that jpanel then another button clicked the same jpanel will appear without opening the current jpanel

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mynumberaddition;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author LAXMI
 */
public class NumberAdditionUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    }
static JFrame k= new JFrame();
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
public static String timeNow() {
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
     return sdf.format(cal.getTime());

}

     /**
     * Creates new form NumberAdditionUI
     */
    public NumberAdditionUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 3, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 204));
        jLabel1.setText("HOTEL MANAGEMENT");

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("HOME");

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("LODGING");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton4.setText("RESTAURENT");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setText("TRAVELS");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("USER ID:");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("PASSWORD:");

        jPasswordField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jPasswordField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton5.setText("SIGNIN");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton6.setText("REGISTER");
        jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton7.setText("TIME AND DATE");
        jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(131, 131, 131)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 179, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 174, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 156, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 151, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(171, 171, 171))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 271, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(124, 124, 124)
                        .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 124, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(144, 144, 144))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField1)
                                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 213, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                        .addContainerGap())))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 58, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton7))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(132, 132, 132)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(248, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jPasswordField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                               

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your choosen the Lodging");
 JPanel n1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8,2));
 k.setBounds(100,100,500, 400);   
     final JLabel labell1,labell2,labell3,labell4,labell5,labell6,labell7;
 final  JTextField lt1,lt3,lt4,lt5,lt6,lt7;
 final JComboBox j=new JComboBox();
 final JButton b1=new JButton("SUBMIT");
 j.addItem("AC");
  j.addItem("NONAC");
   j.addItem("LUXURY");
    j.addItem("NON LUXURY");

labell1=new JLabel("USERID");
lt1=new JTextField(4000);
labell2=new JLabel("ROOM TYPE");
labell3=new JLabel("NO OF ROOMS");
lt3=new JTextField(4000);
labell4=new JLabel("NO OF MEMBERS");
lt4=new JTextField(4000);
labell5=new JLabel("NO OF DAYS");
lt5=new JTextField(4000);
labell6=new JLabel("CHECK IN DATE");
lt6=new JTextField(4000);
labell7=new JLabel("CHECK OUT DATE");
lt7=new JTextField(4000);

n1.add(labell1);
n1.add(lt1);
n1.add(labell2);
n1.add(j);
n1.add(labell3);
n1.add(lt3);
n1.add(labell4);
n1.add(lt4);
n1.add(labell5);
n1.add(lt5);
n1.add(labell6);
n1.add(lt6);
n1.add(labell7);
n1.add(lt7);
n1.add(b1);
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
String lg=lt1.getText();
String lg1=(String)j.getSelectedItem();
String lg2=lt3.getText();
String lg3=lt4.getText();
String lg4=lt5.getText();
String lg5=lt6.getText();
String lg6=lt7.getText();

Connection con = null; 
try { 
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); 
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:RAVI","scott","tiger"); 
Statement statement1=con.createStatement();
Statement st = con.createStatement();
 int j=st.executeUpdate("insert into CHANDUL (USERID2,RTYPE,NROOMS,NMEMBERS,NDAYS,INDATE,OUTDATE) values ('"+lg+"','"+lg1+"','"+lg2+"','"+lg3+"','"+lg4+"','"+lg5+"','"+lg6+"')");;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"DATA SUCCESSFULLY SAVED");

}
catch(Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"PROCESS FAILED!!! insert correct data or choose another userid");
System.out.println(e);
}
}
});

k.add(n1);
        k.setVisible(true);

        // TODO add your handling code here:


        // TODO add your handling code here:


        // TODO add your handling code here:


        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Your choosen the restaurent");
final JPanel n2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,2));
 n2.setBounds(100,100,300, 300); 
 final JLabel labelq1,labelq2,labeltq3,labeltq4;
 final  JTextField tq1,tq2;
 final JButton q1;
 final JComboBox qz=new JComboBox();
 qz.addItem("BREAKFAST");
 qz.addItem("MEALS");
 qz.addItem("DINNER");
 final JComboBox qz1=new JComboBox();
 qz1.addItem("ITEM1");
 qz1.addItem("ITEM2");
 qz1.addItem("ITEM3");
 labelq1=new JLabel("USERID");
tq1=new JTextField(4000);
labelq2=new JLabel("CHECK IN DATE");
tq2=new JTextField(4000);
labeltq3=new JLabel("SESSION");
labeltq4=new JLabel("FOOD ITEMS");
q1=new JButton("SUBMIT");
n2.add(labelq1);
n2.add(tq1);
n2.add(labelq2);
n2.add(tq2);
n2.add(labeltq3);
n2.add(qz);
n2.add(labeltq4);
n2.add(qz1);
n2.add(q1);
q1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
String qtg=tq1.getText();
String qtg1=tq2.getText();
String qtg2=(String)qz.getSelectedItem();
String qtg3=(String)qz1.getSelectedItem();
Connection con = null; 
try { 
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); 
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:RAVI","scott","tiger"); 
Statement statement1=con.createStatement();
Statement st = con.createStatement();
 int j=st.executeUpdate("insert into CHANDUR (USERID1,CDATE,SESSION1,ITEMS) values('"+qtg+"','"+qtg1+"','"+qtg2+"','"+qtg3+"')");;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data is successfully saved");
con.close();
 }
catch(Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"PROCESS FAILED!!! insert correct data");
System.out.println(e);
}
}
});

k.add(n2);
        k.setVisible(true);



        // TODO add your handling code here:

// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Your choosen the travels");
final JPanel n3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8,2));
 k.setBounds(100,100,500, 400);   
     final JLabel labelt1,labelt2,labelt3,labelt4,labelt5,labelt6,labelt7;
 final  JTextField tt1,tt2,tt3,tt5,tt6,tt7;
   final JTextArea tt4;
   final JButton tb1;
labelt1=new JLabel("USERID");
tt1=new JTextField(4000);
labelt2=new JLabel("PICK UP DATA");
tt2=new JTextField(4000);
labelt3=new JLabel("PICK UP TIME");
tt3=new JTextField(4000);
labelt4=new JLabel("PICK UP ADDRESS");
tt4=new JTextArea(5,15);
labelt5=new JLabel("DROP DATE");
tt5=new JTextField(4000);
labelt6=new JLabel("DROP TIME");
tt6=new JTextField(4000);
labelt7=new JLabel("EXTRA DAYS");
tt7=new JTextField(4000);
tb1=new JButton("SUBMIT");
n3.add(labelt1);
n3.add(tt1);
n3.add(labelt2);
n3.add(tt2);
n3.add(labelt3);
n3.add(tt3);
n3.add(labelt4);
n3.add(tt4);
n3.add(labelt5);
n3.add(tt5);
n3.add(labelt6);
n3.add(tt6);
n3.add(labelt7);
n3.add(tt7);
n3.add(tb1);


    tb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
String tg=tt1.getText();
String tg1=tt2.getText();
String tg2=tt3.getText();
String tg3=tt4.getText();
String tg4=tt5.getText();
String tg5=tt6.getText();
String tg6=tt7.getText();
Connection con = null; 
try { 
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); 
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:RAVI","scott","tiger"); 
Statement statement1=con.createStatement();
Statement st = con.createStatement();
 int j=st.executeUpdate("insert into CHANDUK (USERID,PDATE,PTIME,PADDRESS,DDATE,DTIME,E_DAYS) values ('"+tg+"','"+tg1+"','"+tg2+"','"+tg3+"','"+tg4+"','"+tg5+"','"+tg6+"')");;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data is successfully saved");

}
catch(Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"PROCESS FAILED!!! insert correct data");
System.out.println(e);
}
}
});

k.add(n3);
        k.setVisible(true);


        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
Connection con = null; 
try { 
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); 
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:RAVI","scott","tiger"); 
  Statement statement1=con.createStatement();
        PreparedStatement pstmt1=null;
ResultSet rs=null;

String username = new String(jTextField1.getText());
String password = new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword());
pstmt1=con.prepareStatement("select USERID,PWD from chandu where userid=? and pwd=?");
pstmt1.setString(1,username);
pstmt1.setString(2,password);
rs=pstmt1.executeQuery();
if(!rs.next() && rs.getRow() == 0) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Login Failed!! INVALID USERNAME AND PASSWORD");}
else{
jTextField1.setText("");
jPasswordField1.setText("");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"LOGGED IN SUCCESSFULLY");
con.close(); 
 } 
}
catch (Exception e) { 
      System.out.println("fill all the data,verify data,insert correct user id");

  System.out.println(e);// TODO add your handling code here:
    } 

        // TODO add your handling code here:







        // TODO add your handling code here:


        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "ARE YOU READY TO REGISTER?");
final JPanel n = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9,2));
 k.setBounds(100,100,600, 600);   
     final JLabel labelr1,labelr2,labelr3,labelr4,labelr5,labelr6,labelr7,labelr8;
 final  JTextField rt1,rt2,rt3,rt4,rt6,rt8;
   final JTextArea rt7;
    final JPasswordField rt5;
   final JButton rb1;
labelr1=new JLabel("CHOOSE USERID");
rt1=new JTextField(4000);
labelr2=new JLabel("FIRST NAME");
rt2=new JTextField(4000);
labelr3=new JLabel("LAST NAME");
rt3=new JTextField(4000);
labelr4=new JLabel("SURNAME");
rt4=new JTextField(4000);
labelr5=new JLabel("PASSWORD");
rt5=new JPasswordField(4000);
labelr6=new JLabel("EMAIL ID");
rt6=new JTextField(4000);
labelr7=new JLabel("ADDRESS");
rt7=new JTextArea(5,15);
labelr8=new JLabel("CONTACT NUMBER");
rt8=new JTextField(4000);
rb1=new JButton("SUBMIT");
n.add(labelr1);
n.add(rt1);
n.add(labelr2);
n.add(rt2);
n.add(labelr3);
n.add(rt3);
n.add(labelr4);
n.add(rt4);
n.add(labelr5);
n.add(rt5);
n.add(labelr6);
n.add(rt6);
n.add(labelr7);
n.add(rt7);
n.add(labelr8);
n.add(rt8);
n.add(rb1);
rb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
String rg=rt1.getText();
String rg1=rt2.getText();
String rg2=rt3.getText();
String rg3=rt4.getText();
String rg4=rt5.getText();
String rg5=rt6.getText();
String rg6=rt7.getText();
String rg7=rt8.getText();
Connection con = null; 
try { 
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); 
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:RAVI","scott","tiger"); 
Statement statement1=con.createStatement();
Statement st = con.createStatement();
 int j=st.executeUpdate("insert into CHANDU (USERID,FNAME,LNAME,SNAME,PWD,EID,ADDRESS,CONNO) values ('"+rg+"','"+rg1+"','"+rg2+"','"+rg3+"','"+rg4+"','"+rg5+"','"+rg6+"','"+rg7+"')");;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Registered successfully");

}
catch(Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"PROCESS FAILED!!! insert correct data or choose another userid");
System.out.println(e);
}
}
});


k.add(n);
        k.setVisible(true);

        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, timeNow());
      // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {




     /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumberAdditionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumberAdditionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumberAdditionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumberAdditionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new NumberAdditionUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}"
```

Comment: welcome to this forum :-) Please be sure you read the faq, especially those sections about how/what to ask - dumping tons of code and expecting anybody to fix un-described errors is not appropriate ..

Comment: I've got not idea what your actually problem is.  Also, get rid of the paint method at the top of the code, it just presents a nasty blank screen